# HttpPost not working on production server

Tags: java, http, post

I have a back-end application build with Java which at some point needs to post some files in base64 format towards another server. In the development environment everything works smoothly but when put in production it seems like the request gets stuck. This is the code that I'm using for posting the data:

```
        JsonObject tmpObj = new JsonObject();
        tmpObj.add("fileId", examFileName);
        tmpObj.add("username", username);
        tmpObj.add("password", password);
        tmpObj.add("fileList", mediaFiles.toString());
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(tmpObj.toString());
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

In dev env the request is successful for whatever file I'm posting, not dependent on its' size.
This problem happens only in the production server when the base64 representation of a file has a big size (more than 10MB or something like this). Is there any size limit of the post request which I'm breaking? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A server accepting a post usually has a limit on the size of the accepted post. 10MB is a common value on this limit by default. It is very likely that the server in your development environment accepts bigger posts than what the server in your production environment does.

Comment: The server that accepts the request is built with NodeJs. Do you know where can I check this limit?

Comment: No, this is a setting that is specific to each type of server. You have to ask a question on a NodeJs related forum on how to change the limit.

Comment: By the way, this limit is not only imposed by the servers themselves. Sometimes there is loadbalancer in front, especially in production, that could also limit the post size.